# MongoDB Object Id changes while retrieving attributes from CAS

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, cas

Object Id(User Id) of attribute release from CAS server after MongoDB authentication different from the actual Object Id of the User attribute.

I don't know where I went wrong, I can able to get attributes successfully but id retrieved by CAS is somewhat different from actual Object ID in the document of mongo db.

Comment: Could you elaborate more by giving us an example of this case?